# How to avoid overlapping widgets in Android with 'auto-resize.'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight, android-layout-editor

On smaller screens; the editText should let shrink the listView verticaly so it never interferes content-wise. 
Otherwise, when there is a long list of items, the listView should never go over the editText. 
Something like you can see in the image should be avoided.

How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use a constraint or relative layout as the parent, and add a constraint/rule that lays the listview above the edit view.